Coordinates of the axis of a cylinder knowing n-points on its surface
I have n-points in 3D space, with coordinates $P_n(x_n, y_n, z_n)$, distributed on the surface of a cylinder of known radius $r_0$. I also know the direction of the axis of the cylinder thanks to a unit vector $\hat{u}=(a, b, c)$.
My objective is to find the coordinates of a point $A_i(X,Y,Z)$ of the axis of the cylinder in the plane that is perpendicular to $\hat{u}$ and contains both $A_i$, and the $i-th$ point in its surface, with the least number of points possible (Because if I take sufficiently enough points, which in my case will be between 10 and 20, I can just average their coordinates and find a really good approximation for the axis coordinate).
I thought to first find the plane perpendicular to $\hat{u}$ and contains the $i$ point. Then, projecting a second neighbour point $j$ (which I know will not fall over $i$, i.e. it is shifted by an angle). And finally, calculate the coordinates of the center of the circle on that plane (which corresponds to the coordinates of the axis of the cylinder in the plane) by finding the midpoint, finding the line perpendicular to it which using the equation of the perpendicular bisector and the radius of the circle will give me the coordinates of $A_i$.
Then everytime I need to find a new $A_i$ (with a different vector $\hat{u}$), I just need to take 2 new points and redo this.
However this method seems a little tedious and complicated. I am sure there is an easier way to do this. Is there? How can I do this? And if not, how can I improve this method such that it is easy and fast to calculate?

How you find an adjacent point when you do not the LOCATION of the axis?

Find the Cylinder Equation:

given  direction (a,b,c):
4 equations for 4 unknowns: x₀, y₀, z₀, and r.
4 points (x₁,y₁,z₁), (x₂,y₂,z₂), (x₃,y₃,z₃), (x₄,y₄,z₄) on surface, each gives an equation:
[(x₁-x₀)² + (y₁-y₀)² + (z₁-z₀)²][a² + b² + c²] - [(a(x₁-x₀) + b(y₁-y₀) + c(z₁-z₀))²] = r²(a² + b² + c²)
[(x₂-x₀)² + (y₂-y₀)² + (z₂-z₀)²][a² + b² + c²] - [(a(x₂-x₀) + b(y₂-y₀) + c(z₂-z₀))²] = r²(a² + b² + c²)
[(x₃-x₀)² + (y₃-y₀)² + (z₃-z₀)²][a² + b² + c²] - [(a(x₃-x₀) + b(y₃-y₀) + c(z₃-z₀))²] = r²(a² + b² + c²)
[(x₄-x₀)² + (y₄-y₀)² + (z₄-z₀)²][a² + b² + c²] - [(a(x₄-x₀) + b(y₄-y₀) + c(z₄-z₀))²] = r²(a² + b² + c²)

So you need in your case at least 4 points on the surface to find the equation of the cylinder (and an equation for its axis)

@Moti I have an already given distribution of points, all in the surface of the cylinder. By adjacent, I mean "looking from the top of the cylinder, the point that is closest next to the point I am looking for". Sorry if I am not using the right vocabulary I am no mathematician.

Ok, so the minimum is 4; wow, I thought it would be similar to the circle in 2D. I am going to try this as soon as posible.

How you know where to look from? It has to be on the Axis.

@Moti, could you explain the question I don't seem to understand? Are you asking how do I know where the direction of the cylinder is on? I know because I have a unit vector that is also the direction of the cylinder's axis, but I don't know where this axis is.

You need the Axis equation, at least one point on it and then have the axis equation in parametric form or as an intersection of two planes.

Oh okok, I understand, thank you very much. Yes that is not really possible, I do not have that.

Do you have 4 points? Try to allow AI chatbots solve it for you.
